# I am trying to scrape a page with BeautifulSoup in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape this page: http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/en-gb/results///E/10337992/today//////+England+v+Ukraine.html

I am using requests and BeautifulSoup in Python 3. I am specifically trying to extract the text that says 'Draw (13/5)' within the  tag. I have tried to navigate to that spot with BeautifulSoup in many different ways, and it is like BS4 cannot 'see' it...
When I search for all  within , it only gives me the first row.

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th width="41%" scope="col">Market</th>
        <th width="3%"></th>
        <th width="45%" scope="col">Result</th>
        <th width="10%" scope="col" style="text-align: center">Settled</th>
    </tr>
            <tr class="rowGroup top bottom">
                <td style="padding-top: 0pt;" class="borderBottom" rowspan="1">Match Betting</td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                        Draw (13/5) &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td style="padding-top: 0pt; text-align: center" class="borderBottom" rowspan="1">Y</td>
            </tr>
```

How could I best retrieve that information with BeautifulSoup? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Which parser are you using with BS4?

Comment: I have tried with both lxml and html.parser, both have the same issue.

Comment: Give `html5lib` a whirl. I've often found that typically this resolves these types of issues for me when using BS4. Browsers do a great job of parsing badly formatted HTML and this might be what your up against here.

Comment: this page dose not contain the tag you want, are you sure it's the right url, post you complete code, please